# Overlay image is extending outside image - How to stick this to only image

Tags: html, css, overlay

I am trying to put an overlay over an image, but this overlay is extending over the menu bar on top and I don't know how to stick this only on the image.

I have tried to do different things with adjusting the image, changing the position, but it keeps going over the menu bar. When I adjust the top position it is a small fix for full screen, but once on mobile it wont work with the menu being hidden. Also it flows below the image when size changes.

```css
header {
  border-bottom: 5px solid coral;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1647120/pexels-photo-1647120.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.vh-80 {
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.banner-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.bg-overlay>* {
  position: relative;
}

.bg-overlay::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-spaceBetween-middle ">
  <div class="col-2 ">
    <a href="/index.html" class="logo">
      <p>Logo</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="col-10">
    <a href="/#.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="/#.html"></a>
    <a href="/#.html">Business Travel</a>
    <a href="/#.html">Be Inspired</a>
    <a href="/#.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Image banner -->

<section class="grid-spaceAround vh-80 bg-image bg-overlay">
  <div class="col-12-middle banner-text">
    <p>IT'S ALL <strong>GOOD</strong></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried changing the sections, tried things with the relative position, but nothing works.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so easy now seeing this. I was just completely blindstaring. It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `position: relative` on `.bg-image`, and not on every element in overlay `.bg-overlay > *`

```css
header {
  border-bottom: 5px solid coral;
  font-family: Arial;
}

header a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.bg-image {
  background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1647120/pexels-photo-1647120.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: blue;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.vh-80 {
  min-height: 80vh;
}

.banner-text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}


.bg-overlay::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<header class="grid-spaceBetween-middle ">
  <div class="col-2 ">
    <a href="/index.html" class="logo">
      <p>Logo</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <nav class="col-10">
    <a href="/#.html">About Us</a>
    <a href="/#.html"></a>
    <a href="/#.html">Business Travel</a>
    <a href="/#.html">Be Inspired</a>
    <a href="/#.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<!-- Image banner -->

<section class="grid-spaceAround vh-80 bg-image bg-overlay">
  <div class="col-12-middle banner-text">
    <p>IT'S ALL <strong>GOOD</strong></p>
  </div>
</section>
```